# ftplugin not loading

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows

This is my `.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'vim-latex/vim-latex'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/LanguageTool'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'vimoutliner/vimoutliner'
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

set encoding=utf-8
let g:languagetool_jar='$HOME/Downloads/LanguageTool-4.7/languagetool-commandline.jar'

" color scheme
set background=light
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
syntax enable

" tab behaviour
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
"set shiftwidth=4

" UI
set number
set showcmd
set cursorline
filetype plugin indent on

set wildmenu
set lazyredraw
set showmatch
set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT

" searching
set hlsearch
nnoremap <leader><space> :nohlsearch<CR>

" general behaviour
let mapleader=","
set backspace=2
set autoread
set foldmethod=syntax

let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'
```

I have the following files under `C:\Users\Jordi\.vim\after\ftplugin` with different indent settings and other settings

```
/Users/Jordi/.vim/
~ after/ftplugin/
    matlab.vim
    tex.vim
    arduino.vim
+ bundle/
```

The output of `:filetype` yields everything ON

When I check `:scriptnames` the ftplugin scripts are never being loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They only load when you edit a file of that type. Check `:set ft?`—if its one of tex, matlab, or arduino, id expect those to load.

Comment: I mean the OS (just updated the title)

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: `:set ft?` outputs `filetype=tex` so that is okay, why is `tex.vim` not called?

Comment: Unclear. Could be an issue with the runtimepath. Did you try my link above?

Comment: how can I benefit from running vim with a default `.vimrc` if what I try to achieve is enabled through my `.vimrc`

Comment: i think you missed the point—debugging your vimrc is about figuring out where the problem lies. Please do more than glance at the first few lines of the answer. It may be as simple as a plugin issue, or you may need to binary-search your vimrc for the issue. The answer details that

Comment: I tryed with a empty `.vimrc` with only `filetype on` and it still doesnt work, I think it has to do with vim not "seeing" the ftplugin folder

Comment: You need filetype plugin on.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I ment `filetype plugin on`

Comment: Let me clarify what I meant, I open a vim instance with default configuration `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` and then do `filetype plugin on`. Then open a .tex file and the tex.vim plugin is NOT loaded